# How to change the US default dateformat input fields in React-bootstrap-daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm new to React and Javascript and have the following problem: I need to change the default US dateformat in my React-bootstrap-daterangepicker. I found some info about changing the locale object from the momentjs site, but not sure how exactly to implement it... I also tried adding a dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" (and format="DD/MM/YYYY") attribute to my DatePicker but with no success.
My React version is 15.4.0 
Thanks in advance!
[image: Calendar Screenshot]

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ControlLabel, FormGroup, HelpBlock } from 'react-bootstrap';
import DatePicker from "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker";
import moment from 'moment';

class DateRangePicker extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        const value = new Date().toISOString().replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "");
        const date = value;

        this.setState({
            value: date,
            startDate: moment(),
            endDate: moment()

        });

    }

    handleChange(e, datepicker) {
        this.setState({

            startDate: datepicker.startDate,
            endDate: datepicker.endDate,
            value: datepicker.startDate + " to " + datepicker.endDate
        });
        const label = datepicker.startDate + " to " + datepicker.endDate;

        const {startDate, endDate} = datepicker;
        this.props.onSelect(startDate, endDate)
    }

    render() {
        let start = moment(this.state.startDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        let end = moment(this.state.endDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        let dateRange = start + ' to ' + end;
        return (
            <fieldset className="form-group form-group--small pull-left">
                <legend className="hidden">Choose a date range</legend>
                <FormGroup>
                    <ControlLabel className="hidden" htmlFor="dateRange">
                        Date range:</ControlLabel>
                    <DatePicker
                        readOnly="false"
                        startDate={this.start}
                        endDate={this.end}
                        onApply={this
                            .handleChange
                            .bind(this)}
                        onChange={this
                            .handleChange
                            .bind(this)}>
                        <div className="input-group input-group-small">
                            <div className="input-group-addon">
                                <i className="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" id="dateRange" className="form-control" value={dateRange} />

                        </div>
                    </DatePicker>
                    <HelpBlock className="hidden">Help</HelpBlock>
                </FormGroup>

            </fieldset>

        );
    }
}

export default DateRangePicker;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by initializing the locale const in the componentWillMount() method in my compoent i.e

```
    componentWillMount() {
    const value = new Date().toISOString();
    const date = value;
    const locale = locale;

    this.setState({
        value: date,
        locale: {
            'format': 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        },
        startDate: moment(),
        endDate: moment()

    });
   }
```

and then setting a locale attribute for the DatePicker tag:

```
 <DatePicker  locale={this.state.locale}
```

...

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I've been searching everywhere for this, and I come across it in an answer with no votes.

Comment: Thank you, @Owen! I'm glad it helped:) you can vote for it if you haven't done it already...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker#documentation), which refers to the [original project](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker#documentation-and-live-usage-examples), which in turn points to the [probably official site](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage), it seems you could pass to `setState`, along with `startDate` and the like, a `locale` sub-object such as `locale: {format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'}`, as illustrated in [one of the examples](https://gist.github.com/dangrossman/90b0b82275c81ac5904a#file-drp2-js).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I read the documentation but was struggling with the syntax.
I have now managed to solve it though:) Will post it.